# DataGrid and formatting data

Tags: c#, asp.net

I'm new to ASP.NET and don't really understand how to display a table with database data. The data is loaded in an object, where I have a list of objects.

Now I want to show a table with some columns, an image (path created from two fields in the object), an link (passing one field of the object), a textarea (id from object, value from object), a radiobutton (id from object).

How should I do this. I have tried binding a datagrid to the list of objects, and it works. But I don't want to show all data members, and I don't know how to create correct headers and the image and form controls.

```
    ImageDataGridView.DataSource = tradeObj.Images;
    ImageDataGridView.DataBind();
```

Comment: what is tradeObj.Images;

Answer (score 1):

You can spefify your column and header using [boundfield](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.boundfield.aspx)

```
<asp:boundfield datafield="yourColumn"
            headertext="theHeaderText"/>
```

And you need to turn off:

```
ImageDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false
```

To format values look at this [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479342.aspx) at msdn.

Answer (score 1):

To stop the automatic creation of a column for each column in the data source, set:

```
ImageDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false
```

Then you need to define a column for each column in the data source that you want to display - depending on the column you may want a bound column (you can control the format) or something more involved.

See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.datagrid.columns.aspx for a sample and the different column types available

Answer (score 1):

You need to use template field to customize your datagrid as per below

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server">
  <Columns>
    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="True">
      <ItemTemplate>
        <asp:Image runat="server" ID="Image1" 
            ImageUrl="Enabled.gif" />
      </ItemTemplate>
    </asp:TemplateField>
......
......
  </Columns>
</asp:GridView>
```

See this [msdn link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479353.aspx) to work with template field in datagrid

**Update**

For iterate through every row of gridview you need to handle Rowdatabound event as per below.

```
protected void gridView_RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        Image imgCtrl = (Image) e.Row.FindControl("imgCtrl");
        imgCtrl.ImageUrl = "you can apply any format of url here";
    }
}
```

for more information of Rowdatabound event visit [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)

Comment: Thanks, that works for my labels and the textbox. But the image has an url based on the ID and a field called fileExtension in my object. Is there a way to format the url with several fields?

Answer (score 0):

Just set `autogenerate to false`  on your datagrid/gridview control. You can then create a templateField column & drop a label or textbox control inside itemTemplate & bind them like

```
<asp:Label ID="lblMyColumn" Text="<%# Bind("YourColumnName") %>' runat="server"></asp:Label>
```

Alternatively you can also drop a boundField & set its properties

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="YourColumnName" HeaderText="Your Text" SortExpression="YourColumnName" />
```